# Install an extension manually

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

I tried following the link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/alternate-distribution-options) for manual installation of extension but it did not work properly.

Is this method currently not valid? Or do you have manual installation or other APIs provided by edge?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Microsoft Edge are you using? Can you tell us the OS version?  From the document, the External installation of Extension via a preferences json file for macOS are not supported yet.

Comment: Ah. I using Win10 and Edge Version is 80.0.361.66 (Official build) (64-bit). And I knew that :(

Comment: Whether your extension is hosted success? The first step of the document is publish the Extension in the Microsoft Edge Addons success, please refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension) to publish the extension to Microsoft Edge Addons.

Comment: @M.KChe - do you remember if you ever installed your extension and then on the extension page hit REMOVE?  I have a question open and think that Edge has a "problem" with registry installs. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61914537/how-to-distribute-edge-chromium-extension-with-an-msi-through-the-registry