# What notice does a user get from distributed Edge Chromium Extension with an MSI through the registry?

Tags: microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

When the registry keys for an extension are added for Chrome the user is notified of this the next time they start Chrome.  This does not happen for Edge Chromium.

**TEST - App in Microsoft Store - Registry Install**

1. Take [this one for example with ID](https://microsoftedge.microsoft.com/addons/detail/amnbcmdbanbkjhnfoeceemmmdiepnbpp) amnbcmdbanbkjhnfoeceemmmdiepnbpp
2. Use the following to register it in the Registry.

   ```
   [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions\amnbcmdbanbkjhnfoeceemmmdiepnbpp]
   "update_url"="https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx"
   ```
3. Start Edge
4. There is no window notification that a new extension is being installed. (Chrome shows a window).
5. The extension is installed but disabled.
6. A small orange dot appears on the top right for about 1 second but then disappears.  See pic
   [image: pic of orange dot.]

This is not satisfactory for a user as it would mean they would have to wait for Edge to sync up new extensions and then go to the extensions page to enable it. Chrome shows a window at the top right first, which the user can then click on to enable the extension.  Only if the user does not see or click on the window does this orange icon appear, but the icon stays there long enough for a user to see it and click on it, which if I recall correctly leads them to the extensions page.

1. Is this intended from Microsoft or a bug in the user interface.?
2. Where do I report this as a bug?

**EDIT BASED ON BELOW ANSWER**
I must have a different Edge Chromium and Google Chrome to you.  I have uploaded two videos of how extensions install when opening the browser after the keys are added.

[This is the Google Chrome way.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kONnh0RxGSI) You see that you get a proper notification withOUT user interaction and clicking Enable, enables it.

[This is my Edge Chromium (Version 83.0.478.37 (Official build) (64-bit))](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fy3dwvbjeV8) with a dot for about a second.

Also Adding the keys to CurrentUser Hive is the only way it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You had asked,"**When installing Edge Extension using the following Registry, Edge won’t show installation progress window/bar to notify a user if the extension is completely installed. Whilst Chrome does show a window at the top right first, which the user can then click on to enable the extension.**"

•   According to the Edge official document [Alternate Method of Distributing Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/alternate-distribution-options), we suggest registering the extension under **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE rather than HKEY_CURRENT_USER**.

Find or create the following key in the registry:

> 32-bit Windows: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions
>
> 64-bit Windows:
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions

•   Try to import the registry key > Start Edge > A small orange dot appears on the top right.

It won’t disappear until User clicks it and then a message prompts User to enable or remove the extension.

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Edge\Extensions\amnbcmdbanbkjhnfoeceemmmdiepnbpp]
>
> "update_url"=https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx

[image]

once extension installed, the extension state is disabled. We should enable it manually.

[image]

Even Chrome won’t enable Extension automatically after installed through the registry. So it’s by-design feature.

Comment: I have added more information to my question including video's of how Edge and Chrome actually work or don't. Sorry I am not a you tube expert, somehow the video is mirrored.

Comment: Your Edge Version is the same as mine. It's exactly the latest version. It's weird that the dot only keeps for a second in your environment. Have you tried other computers? And what's your OS version?

Comment: Sorry I missed this comment. I have tested on Windows 10 Enterprise 1809 and on Windows 10 Pro 1909.  But If I understand you correctly Edge (unlike Chrome) ONLY shows the orange dot and users are supposed to know what that means?  If this is the case it does not really matter how long it shows, I am going to have to annoy the users by opening the browser myself somehow and directing it to the extensions page (not sure if that is even possible) with a dialog explaining to them what to do.

Comment: Just for completeness I would like to suggest that Microsoft copy the notification as done by Chrome, do you have a link where this can be done?

Comment: You can just go to 'settings and more' on the top right corner of Edge -> 'Help and Feedback' -> 'Send feed back' to deliver your suggestions.